# How to filter based on a joined tables relations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I don't write much raw SQL so I apologize in advance. Most of my necessary queries resolve within the framework's methods & active record. Hopefully I can explain my question well: I have 3 models:

```rb
class Home < ApplicationRecord

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
# has an attribute "max_number" with the maximum number of users allowed to belong.
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_and_belongs_to_many :homes
has_many :roles, as: :roleable
```

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true
# has an attribute "name" with the name of the role
```

I want to fetch all of the homes that have users with any role name except for "owner" and with a max # of 2 users associated. I've tried a number of things similar to this query:

```rb
Home.joins(user: :roles).group('user.id').having('COUNT(CASE WHEN roles.name != "owner" THEN 1 END) > max_number')
```

But this does not yield the intended result. This seems to includes records that already have 2 users belonging, and does not seem to be impacted by the `roles.name` portion.

My wording may be confusing: I essentially need to be able to count the number of roles without name "owner" of a user and fetch homes based on that being less than 2.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are your table definitions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be strictly SQL based solution you can always use Ruby and Rails to look for this homes.

You can use `select` method on `Home.all` collection to return all elements which pass the condition provided in block. Just like this:

```
Home.all.select { |h| h.users.map(&:role).exclude?('owner') && h.users.count < 3 }
```

Please note that `exclude?` is Rails method if you would like to use Ruby based solution you can always reach for `include?` and place `!` in front of the statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @somethingsomeone were you able to solve your problem?